# d3 react js - Failed to execute 'createElementNS' on 'Document': The qualified name provided contains the invalid character ','

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, ecmascript-6

I am trying to create a d3 line chart in a component method:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {observer, inject} from "mobx-react";

import {line, select} from "d3"

@inject("store")
@observer
class PriceChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.createLineChart = this.createLineChart.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.createLineChart()
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.createLineChart()
  }
  createLineChart() {

    const data = [
      {
        price: 100
      }, {
        price: 200
      }
    ]

    const node = this.node

    const priceLine = line().x((d) => 1).y((d) => d.price)

    select(node).append(priceLine(data))
  }
  render() {
    return <svg ref={node => this.node = node} width={800} height={800}></svg>
  }
}

export default PriceChart;
```

But I am getting the following error:

> Failed to execute 'createElementNS' on 'Document': The qualified name
>   provided ('M1,100L1,200') contains the invalid character ','..

So where are the value M1, L1, coming from? It seems that d3 is adding values to the data that are causing it to error?

Comment: Seems like the timestamp isn't regarded as a valid number to use on you d3 chart, which is why you're gr

Comment: @Pineda I tried playing around with my inputs a bit - changed all the prices to fixed numbers, changed all the timestamps to a unix timestamp, then just changed the x function to always return 1, but I always get some variation of this error - contains the invalid character ','..

Comment: @Pineda edited the question to a much simpler example taht still shows the issue

Answer (score 0):

This...

```
const priceLine = line().x((d) => 1).y((d) => d.price)
```

... is a *line generator*.

Therefore, what it does is this: if you pass it a given data array...

```
priceLine(data)
```

... it returns a string with the path commands. Like this:

```
"M1,100L1,200"
```

So, it makes little sense appending this string as a SVG element.

**Solution**:

What you want here is to append a **path** element, and setting this string as its `d` attribute. Therefore, it should be:

```
select(node).append("path")//append a path here
    .attr("d", priceLine(data))//and set its d attribute
```